# How does a IList.Distinct method throws ArgumentNullException in the given scenario

Tags: c#, linq

I am facing a very weird issues and not sure where the problem is. When I walk through the code and analyze all the scenario, I do not
see that in any case it can through ArgumentNullException.

But somehow in production server, it throws the following exception:

> Exception details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: source
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>   at GetDistinctValues(IList`1 textNames)

I have extracted the code in a sample console application. Can anyone tell me the possible scenarios when GetDistinctValues method can throw this ArgumentNullException?

Sample code snippet:

```
private IList<string> GetDistinctValues(IList<string> textNames)
{
    var values = GetTextValues(textNames);
    var trimmedValues = values.Select(value => value.Trim());
    return trimmedValues.Distinct(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase).ToList();
}

public static IList<string> GetTextValues(IList<string> textNames)
{
    var values = new List<string>();
    var names = (List<string>)textNames;
    if (!names.Any())
    {
        return null;
    }

    names.ForEach(x => values.Add(GetValue(x)));

    return values;
}

private static string GetValue(string name)
{
    // returns some value depending on name

    return "someValue";
}
```

Comment: `if (!names.Any())
        {
            return null;
        }` in `GetTextValues` looks like a candidate

Comment: Yeah, I also think `!names.Any()`  is the possible culprit, because that would fail if `names` is null

Comment: The exception shows - System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source). Could  return trimmedValues.Distinct(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase).ToList();, where I convert it to ToList() can also generate this exception?

Comment: Maybe this : From : var names = (List<string>)textNames; To : var names = textNames.Select(x => (string)x).ToList();

Comment: The fact that the exception is thrown at that line doesn´t neccessarily - in particular not when using Linq which is designed deferredly - mean, that line also causes the error. ToList just forces the previous methods to be called now, and one of those throws the exception.

Comment: When 'trimmedValues' is null this exception occurs, Please check, if its null return empty string instead of null,

Comment: @SanjeevS How can `trimmedValues` possibly be null? It's the result of a `Select` statement, which does not return null.

Comment: @stuartd But then the exception would be on the `var trimmedValues = values.Select()` line.

Comment: Please provide complete [MCVE] - the sample data is missing so it is hard to guess which of theses lines causing error this time. (I.e. why one would cast `IList<T>` to `List<T>` or use `Enumerable.Any()` instead of `List.Count`, why would you return `null` for collection and not check result of the call...)

Comment: Change `if (!names.Any())` to `if (names.Count == 0) return names;`.

Answer (score 0):

`ToList` is an extension method, probably with a signature like this: `public static List<T> ToList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)`. And reading the exception, `source` is null. Ergo, `GetTextValues` returns null. Which it does when there are no `names`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your collections in LINQ, the you should 
**Never! Ever!** return null if you have nothing to return. Instead you should return Enumerable.Empty, or an empty collection. If your function decides that it has no elements to return it should sill return an enumerator, in this case the enumerator that enumerates no elements.

Consider changing your function:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetTextValues(IEnumerable<string> textNames)
{
    if (textNames == null)
        return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
        // or consider: throw ArgumentNullException(nameof(textNames));
    return textNames.Select(textName => GetValue(textName));
}
```

The nice thing about returning an enumerable instead of a List, is that if users of your function only need the first few elements of your list, only few elements are created.